# Online gallery software that has good integration with lightroom Classic CC

Tags: photography, gallery

I'm looking for online gallery software that has good integration with Lightroom Classic CC.

My prerequisites:

- Easy publishing from within Lightroom Classic CC with e.g. a plugin software
- Should be installable on my own personal server and be served as a
  subdomain of my personal website, like: http://photos.example.com
- Tags, including people-tags and geotags should be exported. In the
  gallery, you should be able to easily search on any tag, person's
  name or location
- Access control: the site is intended for family
  pictures, so only family members get a password and should be granted
  access.
- Makes use of modern HTML5/CCS3/responsive web design. Since
  the intended audience is quite small (my immediate family), I don't
  care if older browsers aren't supported.